# redux-form dynamic wizard

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to create a wizard (form) with a dynamic number of steps (with redux-form).
At every step, the user can either go to the last step of the wizard or add an extra step.

An example would be a wizard to order a customizable item. Each step of the wizard contains all the fields to configure the item. The user can then either add another item and configure it or go to the checkout (last step of the wizard).

I'm following the [Wizard example](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/wizard/) but I'm unsure how to add steps dynamically. I tried mixing it up with a FieldArray without success.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for my work. For your case, if a user selects a certain answer on the same page, you can just do conditional rendering for showing the next page/dynamic values.

My case also had conditional rendering. I had to use formValueSelector API to access form values on different pages. Here is the modified wizard code from the redux-form example Wizard. If you choose male on second page, you get favorite color dropdown question on third page. If you choose female, you get an employed checkbox question.

I made a conditional variable of isMale and return different Field depending on if male answer is true or not. I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but this is one way that worked for me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/34jp9rqp71

I just modified/added these parts of the code.

**WizardFormThirdPage.js**

```
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

let WizardFormThirdPage = props => {
  const { sex, handleSubmit, pristine, previousPage, submitting } = props;
  var isMale = sex == "male" ? true : false;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {isMale && (
        <div>
          <label>Favorite Color</label>
          <Field name="favoriteColor" component={renderColorSelector} />
        </div>
      )}
      {!isMale && (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="employed">Employed</label>
          <div>
            <Field
              name="employed"
              id="employed"
              component="input"
              type="checkbox"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      . . .
    </form>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  sex: formValueSelector("wizard")(state, "sex")
});
WizardFormThirdPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(WizardFormThirdPage);
```

Comment: in your example you already have a set of steps. whats being asked is different. OP is asking if its possible to add a new step based on a response from server which may require a new step or abort.